# Getting ArrayList Size on jsp page

Tags: java, list, jsp

hi I am trying to get the total size of an arraylist but for some reason this is not being shown the code below is used to show the size.

```
    <%db.DBConnection db = new  db.DBConnection(); 
            ArrayList<User> myUsers =db.getAllUsers();
            %>  

   Total Subscribed Users: <p><% myUsers.size();%></p>
```

Thanks

Comment: Maybe this will help. http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bnaov.html

Answer (score 13):

Some of this is clearly ripe for moving out of JSP, but based on how it looks like your classes and methods are defined, this should work (JSP + JSTL):

```
<jsp:useBean id="db" class="db.DBConnection"/>
<c:set var="myUsers" value="${db.allUsers}"/>
Total Subscribed Users: <p>${fn:length(myUsers)}</p>
```

Comment: thank you very much, this is exactly what I was looking for, it should be set as the correct answer.

Comment: Yes I agree, using the jsp 'functions' capability is the right answer.

Answer (score 5):

does this work?

```
<p><%= myUsers.size()%></p>
```

I suggest that write as less java codes as possible in your jsp. You could consider to use some taglib, jstl. for example. Put all business codes on your server side.  specially  things like `b.DBConnection db = new  db.DBConnection();`

Comment: As an addition, this would be a good read: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3180202/814702

Comment: And please remove semicolon. Quote from "Head First Servlets and JSP": **Expressions become the argument to an out.print()**.
In other words, the Container takes everything you type between 
the `<%=`  and `%>` and puts it in as the argument to a 
statement that prints to the implicit response `PrintWriter out`.

Comment: The valid expression is `<%= myUsers.size() %>`. Semicolon is invalid inside an expression element in a JSP page.

Comment: @informatik01 thank you for pointing it out. I just copy/paste his codes and added an "=".

Answer (score 0):

```
 int count = myUsers.size();
            %>  
            <h1>User Management</h1>
            Total Subscribed Users: <p><%=count%></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should do this to achieve that purpose:

```
Total Subscribed Users: <p><%= myUsers.size(); %></p>
```

Alternatively, you can also do:

```
Total Subscribed Users: <p><% out.print(String.valueOf(myUsers.size()));%></p>
```

The block of code you wrote in your question was a "scriplet".  By itself, a scriptlet doesn't contribute any HTML.

See [this](http://www.jsptut.com/scriptlets.jsp) for more details.